# Kubernetes : How to make another person access kubernetes cluster with edit clusterRole permissions?

Tags: authentication, kubernetes

I did this:

1. I created a service account

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: myname
...
```

2. I generate the token from the secret created in the service account:

`token=$(kubectl get secrets myname-xxxx-xxxx -o jsonpath={.data.token} | base64 --decode)`

3. I set credentials for the serviceAccount `myname` created:
   `kubectl config set-credentials myname --token=$token`
4. I created a context
   `kubectl config set-context myname-context --cluster=my-cluster --user=myname`
5. then I created a copie of ~/.kube/config and delete the cluster-admin entries (letting only the user myname)
6. I rolebinded the user to a specific namespace with the edit clusterRole permissions:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata: 
  name: dev-access
  namespace: my-ns
roleRef: 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
subjects: 
  - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: User
    name: myname
EOF
```

7. I sent the edited `~/.kube/config` to the person who want to access the cluster, now he can lists the pods but not exec into them:

**Error**

```
(Forbidden): pods "pod-xxxxx-xxxx" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:myname" cannot create resource "pods/exec" in API group "" in the namespace "my-ns"
```

I want to do that from a non master machine which have the master `~/.kube/config` copied into it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RoleBinding` that you have is binding the `ClusterRole` to a `User` and not a `ServiceAccount`. The error clearly shows a ServiceAccount `system:serviceaccount:default:myuser` So the `RoleBinding` should be as below

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata: 
  name: dev-access
  namespace: my-ns
roleRef: 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
subjects: 
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: myuser
    namespace: default
EOF
```

To verify all permissions of the `ServiceAccount` `myuser` use below command

```
kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:default:myuser
```

To verify specific permission of `pods/exec` of the `ServiceAccount` `myuser` use below command

```
kubectl auth can-i create pods/exec --as=system:serviceaccount:default:myuser
```

Comment: the permissions of the sa for pod are: 
```
pods                                            []                  []               [get list watch]
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something from a pod? That would use a service account by default and you need to give RoleBinding to the service account as I have in my answer

Comment: exactly, thank you I changed the subject kind to ServiceAccount and I deleted apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io from subject

Comment: also I  add "namespace: default" to subject

Comment: I'm having an issue, I'm getting disconnected from the pod in a few seconds after exec-ing into it, my internet connection is stable.

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question with details